# UBlock Origin: Blocking specific advertisement on YouTube via custom filtering

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, ublock-origin

There is a slightly annoying advertisement box outside of the video in the newest YouTube redesign:

[image: YouTube screenshot]

[Here's a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfTuvOSSUSo) to the example video I used in this case, but the box appears on many other monetized videos.

If I add a filter, it adds a very long advertisement string to my filter list. This string is probably unique.

[image: Filtering]

I've tried blocking elements like these before. The elements are usually back after a page reload.

How do you block these unique elements? If I block its container - which has the nice name ##container - it's going to block every single container on the site, leaving me with only the video.

Comment: I don't see that ads. Use updated Ublock Origin extension. From the second image, you may use this URL as filter `googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads`.

Comment: @Biswa Doesn't Chrome automatically update extensions?

Comment: @Biswa Where do I enter that filter? Entering it in the "Block element" menu doesn't do much.

Comment: Click on the ublock icon, select my filters tab, paste the url, click on apply, reload YouTube.